# Samsung S5 Graphics Error under Lineage

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, lineageos, graphics

I just got a refurbished S5 and installed the latest Lineage OS ([lineage-14.1-20171123-nightly-klte-signed](https://download.lineageos.org/klte) on it. Most of the time everything works normal. Sometimes, however, the graphics gets really weird (see images). [image: Strange graphics errors]
Other family members have the same phone and I also flashed Lineage on them without experiencing these problems. Therefore, it cannot be a general problem. Any ideas about what might be wrong with the phone and how to fix it?

Edit: This problem was also reported [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/help/graphics-overlapping-issues-t2987899) but no solution was documented.

Comment: Please see [Recommendation for questions pertaining to a problem specific to a nightly build of a ROM](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2077/16575); these kind of issues are better reported to the resp. ROM tracker.

Answer (score 0):

A nightly build is a BUGGY build . A different one is compiled EVERY NIGHT , and that’s why its called a nightly build.
This is how bugs are corrected. Enthusiasts and developers try out the new build and try find the bugs and solve them so that the next nightly build will have less bugs. After some some weeks/months , they manage to make a build stable enough to be used on a daily basis. This is the build that ordinary people download.

You should use the stable build if you want a stable OS. Stable builds might be released once a month or once in two months.